# I'm unable to insert values into a column that was created as a result of a 1:N relationship using TypeORM

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

advertiser and advertisement-request tables have a 1:N relationship, and I have configured the entities accordingly. However, I'm unable to insert the advertiserId into the advertiserId column of the advertisement-request table. How can I resolve this issue?

```
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';
import {Column ,CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn, ManyToOne, RelationId} from 'typeorm';
import {Advertiser} from "./advertiser.entity";

@Entity('advertisement_request')
export class AdvertisementRequest {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;    
@Column()
    companyName: string;    
@Column()
    companyRegisterNumber: string;    
@Column()
    productName: string;    
@Column()
    creatorSubscriberRangeId: number;    
@Column()
    creatorHeadcount: number;    
@CreateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)'})
        createdAt: Date;    
@UpdateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamp', 
default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)'})
updatedAt: Date;    

@ManyToOne(() => Advertiser)
advertiser: Advertiser
    @RelationId((advertisementRequest : AdvertisementRequest) => advertisementRequest.advertiser)
    advertiserId: number;}
```

```
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
    OneToMany
} from 'typeorm';
import {AdvertisementRequest} from "./advertisement-request.entity";

@Entity('advertiser')
export class Advertiser {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Exclude()
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  password: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
  default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)'
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)'
  })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => AdvertisementRequest, advertisementRequest => advertisementRequest.advertiser)
  advertisementRequests: AdvertisementRequest[];
}
```

```
advertisement-request.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AdvertiseRequestDto } from "./dto/advertise-request.dto";
import { AdvertisementRequest } from "../common/entities/advertisement-request.entity";
import { AdvertisementRequestRepository } from "./advertisement-request.repository";
import { AdvertiserRepository } from "../advertiser/advertiser.repository";


@Injectable()
export class AdvertisementRequestService {
    constructor(
        private readonly AdvertisementRequestRepository: AdvertisementRequestRepository,
        private readonly advertiserRepository: AdvertiserRepository
    ) {}

    async advertiseRequest(
        advertisementData: AdvertiseRequestDto,
        decodeJwt: any
        ): Promise<AdvertisementRequest>{
      const { companyName, companyRegisterNumber, productName, creatorSubscriberRangeId, creatorHeadcount } = advertisementData;
      const advertisementRequest = new AdvertisementRequest();

        advertisementRequest.companyName = companyName;
        advertisementRequest.companyRegisterNumber = companyRegisterNumber;
        advertisementRequest.productName = productName;
        advertisementRequest.creatorSubscriberRangeId = creatorSubscriberRangeId;
        advertisementRequest.creatorHeadcount = creatorHeadcount;
        advertisementRequest.advertiserId = decodeJwt.advertiserId; //not inserted in column



        const saveAdvertisementRequest = await this.AdvertisementRequestRepository.save(advertisementRequest);
          return saveAdvertisementRequest;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to
advertisementRequest.advertiserId = decodeJwt.advertiserId;  and save advertisementRequest but
its undefined(maybe null)

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @LajosArpad no, it works but not inserted advertiseId in column